# Destructuring components in codepen

Tags: reactjs, destructuring, codepen

I'm just testing out this code in codepen

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const greeting = 'Welcome to React';

    return (
      <div>
        <Greeting greeting={greeting} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const Greeting = ({ greeting }) => <h1>{greeting}</h1>;

React.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

It doesn't render but if i write it as a class it does, anybody know how to fix it?

Comment: I've checked in codesandbox.io (it's easier there to select dependencies needed) and everything is fine there. so either provide error message if you see any or add link to your codepen

Comment: No error message is given it just doesn't work, i'll try codesandbox and leave this open in case anyone else has an answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have imports in your file?

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const greeting = 'Welcome to React';

    return (
      <div>
        <Greeting greeting={greeting} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const Greeting = ({ greeting }) => <h1>{greeting}</h1>;

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Also looks like you have type in the last line. Should be `ReactDom`

Here the link to codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/5yl153nyxk

Comment: I tried it with the import statements and changed the reactdom.render but it does not work